# How do I access iron-router path variables in Template.x.rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor

### Background

In the iron-router path definition you can use variables, like in this example in the docs:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#controlling-subscriptions

This is all fine and it does exactly what I want except I son't want to do this in the waitOn clause but in the rendered callback for a specific sub template. I have several of these and I would like them to render independently and not on load as waitOn suggests.

My router looks like this:

```
Router.map( function () {
  this.route('de', {
    path: '/monitor/DE/:period',
    data: function () { 
      return {subtitle: "Germany - " + this.params.period + " data"}; 
    }
  });
});
```

I also have some template code that run on rendered to draw a d3 graph. In this function I define a Deps.autorun containing a subscription.

```
Template.de.rendered(function (){
  // lots of d3 stuff...

  // Automatically redraw on change
  Deps.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe("count", "hourly");
  });
});
```

I publish the collection with _id as timestamps using a parameter like this:

```
Meteor.publish("count", function(period) {
  if(period == "hourly") {
    return Count.find({_id: {$gt: new Date().getTime() - 3.6e6*24}}, 
                        {sort: {_id: -1}});
  } else {
    return Count.find({_id: {$gt: new Date().getTime() - 3.6e6*24*30}}, 
                        {sort: {_id: -1}});
  }
});
```

This code works fine, but I have hard coded the parameter in the subscription. I would like to use the path variable to change the subscription scope.

### Question

How can i use an iron-router path variable to change a subscription in the Template.x.rendered callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
Router.current().params
```

Comment: Omg. I checked that in the console before but then it didn't work. Adding it to the subscription solved it! Thanks!